# Magento - Bulk attribute value deletion

Tags: magento

I need to delete values for `image`, `small_image`, and `thumbnail` attributes in all products. How can I go about doing this in Magento? I'm running Magento 1.5.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Truncate the tables: `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` and `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` if you are using a Flat catalog you'll need to rebuild it after doing such.  System->Index Management.

SQL (run this at your own risk, ive not tested it):

```
TRUNCATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`; 
TRUNCATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
```

Comment: Only images that I've uploaded manually through Magento show up here. The majority of my image attributes have been set through the Import function. These values are showing up in `catalog_product_entity_varchar` along with almost every single other attribute. They are associated with their respective `attribute_id`.